# Kivy Voice recognition is not converting speech to text

Tags: python, android, kivy, voice-recognition, kivymd

my code is recording voice, but for some reason google recognizer or sphinx not converting the voice to text. If i print the audio there is voice. the output is "Sorry, I did not get that" witch is the exception default. Can you look in to my code and see what I'm doing wrong. In regular Python this Voice recognition work fine. `

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock, mainthread
import speech_recognition as sr
from kivy.lang import Builder
from plyer import stt
from plyer import tts

Builder.load_string("""
<Principal>:
    id: HomeScreen
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text:'speak'
            on_release: root.Btnclick()
        Label:
            id: lblMessage
            text: 'Hello' """)

class Principal(Screen):
    def Btnclick(self):
        self.ids.lblMessage.text = "Say something!"
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda d: self.GetAudio(), 0)
 
    def GetAudio(self):
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        r.energy_threshold =4000
        r.dynamic_energy_threshold = True
        
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source,duration=5)
            #r.energy_threshold = 400  
            r.dynamic_energy_threshold = True 
            print("Say something!")  
            audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            print("you Said: "+r.recognize_sphinx(audio, language = "en-US"))
            #tts.speak("you Said: "+r.recognize_sphinx(audio, language = "en-US"))
            self.ids.lblMessage.text = "you Said: "+r.recognize_sphinx(audio, language = "en-US")
        except:
            print("Sorry, I did not get that")
            #tts.speak("Sorry, I did not get that")
            self.ids.lblMessage.text = "Sorry, I did not get that"

class MainApp(App):
 
    def build(self):
        for i in sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names():
            print(i)
        sm = ScreenManager()
        self.sm = sm
        sm.add_widget(Principal(name='Principal'))
        return sm
 
    def on_pause(self):
        return False
                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

This is the output am getting

```
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
Say something!
<speech_recognition.AudioData object at 0x0000027124A64190>
Sorry, I did not get that
```

Comment: After examining my microphone on my laptop, the microphone is working fine. Even speech recognition on regular python is not working any more. Can any one help me with this please, I'm stuck from going forward and transferring my code to my Android.